# Why am I getting a float, not a double, from scanf?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse

Recently was writing small programs with fp numbers.
First I read double fp into aligned locations(for *SSE* instructions)

```
    segment .data
scanf_fmt:
        db "%f%ld", 0

    segment .bss
    align 16, db 0
x      resq 1      ; for double fp
number resq 1      ; for integer
    align 16, db 0
res    resq 1      ; for double fp

lea rdi, [fmt]
lea rsi, [x]
lea rdx, [number]
xor eax, eax ; number of fp values(edited from mov rax, 1 ,still looks the same)
call scanf
```

Then I move double:

```
movsd xmm0, [x]
```

Then I began debugging:  **I typed in `1.6`** for scanf to read.

```
100 movsd xmm0, [x]
(gdb) p/f x
$1 = 1.60000002
(gdb) n
(gdb) p $xmm0
$2 = {v4_float = {1.600000002, 0, 0, 0}, v2_double = {5.2..., 0}, ...
```

Floating-point value at label `x` moved but as float(`movss`) not as double(`movsd`, which I used)

What's going on here?

Comment: You need to show your complete program, how you built it, how you ran it and what you typed when you ran it. You also need say what you expected to be displayed in the debugger instead.

Comment: `mov rax, 1` is a bug.  You're passing a pointer-to-double in an integer register, and zero FP args in xmm regs.

Comment: @RossRidge Build: `yasm -f elf64 -g dwarf2 main.asm; gcc -o main main.o`
Run: `./main`
Typed: `1.6`
Expect something like `{v4_float = {smth, 0, 0, 0}, v2_double = {1.6, 0}, ...`

Comment: You shouldn't expect the 2nd element of v4_float to be zero, unless the double has the low 32 bits of the mantissa all zero.  (This is only likely if it's exactly representable, like 0.5 or an integer or something)

Comment: More importantly, what format string did you use?

Comment: @PeterCordes: `scanf_fmt db "%f%ld", 0`. Edited the question to reflect this. Read also integer value, but did not wrote in question initially, thought does not matter.

Comment: You still left the format string out of the question.

Comment: Added it, it is in data section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `scanf(3)`:

> `%f`      Matches an optionally signed floating-point number; the next pointer must be a pointer to `float`.

So scanf stored a 32-bit single-precision `float` into `[x]`, like you told it to.  The next 32 bits remain zero.

Everything else you saw is an obvious consequence of that.

---

The conversion specifier for `double` is `%lf`, like you can quickly find by searching for "double" in the man page.

Comment: How to read with scanf double floating point number exactly? So that the scanf will place 8 byte double in memory location according to IEEE 754, not just the 4 byte single-precision float. Their formats are similar but nevertheless it is not possible to make double out of float just with padding 4 zero bytes at the front of float.

Comment: search for `double` in the man page like a normal person.  It's the same as if you were doing this in C.

Comment: Ah, obvious, need to read mans("lf" for reading double). Now xmm0 in gdb printed as expected.